# How to show overlay internal link on top of the current one when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, overlay

I would like to make an onclick button which slides in another page link and changes the  URL that covers up 80% of the website, while the previous page stays in the background. When close, the URL returns to the previous one.

I thought of ways to achieve that, but none of them changes the URL of the page, such as

- embed iframe element
- overlay a div element
- make a pop up

Like this site, page slides in when clicked and changes the URL 
https://area17.com/work

Comment: well I also wanna know this !

Comment: The new URL in the address bar, "https://area17.com/work/fondation-louis-vuitton-website" is not showing popup when copied and pasted directly in another tab. It's just changing the content of the address bar like 

```window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/another-new-url");```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by any of the methods you specified above by adding the following Javascript code for changing the URL without reloading the page.

```
window.history.pushState(state, pageTitle, theUrl);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for, however, it creates a fake URL entry point that cannot be linked back to if you copy and paste the address directly, does that mean the page created upon changing the URL cannot be found on SEO?

Answer (score 0):

**ping me if you looking for this**

```css
.portfolio-overlay {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  opacity: 0.75;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:black;
  top:-100%;
  transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out;
  display:block;
    
}
.portfolio-overlay a.demoLink{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute
}
.portfolio-overlay div {
    position:relative;
  display:inline-block;;
    
}

ul.portfolio-project-image { 
    list-style: none; 
    width:100% 

}

ul.portfolio-project-image li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li:hover .portfolio-overlay {
  top: 0;
  display:block;

    
}
.bt4 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 160px;
    font: 200 12px/1.3 'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI Light', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color:#FFF;
    width:100%;
    height:10px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.bt5 {
    text-align: center;
    font: 100 14px/1.3 'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI Light', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color:#FFF;
    width:100%;
    height:10px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.portfolio-project {
    width: 32%;
    height: 373px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin-left:15px;
    float:left;
}


.portfolio-project-image{
    width: 100%;
    height: 373px;
}

.portfolio-project-image-one{
    width: 100%;
    height: 373px;
    background-image:url(../images/flyer_mock_up.jpg);
    background-position:center;
}



.portfolio-project-image-one:hover{
    width: 100%;
    height: 373px;
    background-image:url(../images/flyer_mock_up.jpg);
    background-position:center;
    display:block;
}

.bt5 a {
    text-align: center;
    font: 100 14px/1.3 'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI Light', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color:#FFF;
    width:100%;
    height:10px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-project-container">
<div class="portfolio-project">
<div class="portfolio-project-image">
<ul class="portfolio-project-image">
    <li>
    <p>
    Other page details
    </p>
        <div class="portfolio-project-image-one"></div>
        <div class="portfolio-overlay"><a class="demoLink" href="#"></a><div class="bt4">facebook</div><div class="bt5"><a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="html5lightbox" data-width="853" data-height="480" title=""> visit facebook</a></div><div class="bt6"></div></div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```